# Android Robolectric and vector drawables

Tags: android, robolectric, android-vectordrawable

I am using some vector drawables in my app but only for v21 and up - they are in the resource folder drawable-anydpi-v21 and also have fallback bitmap versions for the other api levels (drawable-hdpi.mdpi,...).

When I run a robolectric with this config

```
@Config(sdk = 16, application = MyApp.class, constants = BuildConfig.class, packageName = "com.company.app")
```

I get the following error on inflate of the views using these drawables

```
Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: File ./app/build/intermediates/data-binding-layout-out/dev/debug/drawable-anydpi-v21/ic_info_outline_white_24dp.xml from drawable resource ID #0x7f02010e
Caused by: org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParserException: XML file ./app/build/intermediates/data-binding-layout-out/dev/debug/drawable-anydpi-v21/ic_info_outline_white_24dp.xml line #-1 (sorry, not yet implemented): invalid drawable tag vector
```

the relevant parts of the build.gradle are:

```
   android {
      compileSdkVersion 23
      buildToolsVersion "23.0.3"
      defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.app"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 79
        versionName "0.39"
        // Enabling multidex support.
        multiDexEnabled true
        vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true

        testApplicationId "com.example.app.test"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
      }
      testOptions {
        unitTests.returnDefaultValues = true
      }
   }
   dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:support-vector-drawable:23.4.0'
    testCompile "org.robolectric:robolectric:3.1"
    testCompile "org.robolectric:shadows-multidex:3.1"
    testCompile "org.robolectric:shadows-support-v4:3.1"
   }
```

So it looks as though even though i have specified sdk=16 Robolectric seems to take the drawables from drawable-anydpi-v21.

1. Is this a bug is roboelectric?  or
2. Is there a better way to specify what the APK level is? or
3. Is there a way to let roboelectric read the vector tag? or
4. Some other way of doing it?

Comment: Can you show your `build.gradle`? To make sure how do you use vector drawables

Comment: build.gradle added

Comment: It doesn't work like this do you have `defaultConfig {  
     vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true  
    } `?

Comment: doh! actually that was what i had but i deleted the wrong lines. i have updated it

Comment: Is it solved, write your answer

Comment: No - i already had those lines in the build.gradle. so the question stands as written

Comment: Then I would say it is a bug for the Robolectric. It is hard to be on par with android and support libraries releases. Why you're testing api 16?

Comment: Just because I wanted the robolectric to use the bitmap drawables - not the vectors. I understand robolectric can lag behind behind as it must be hard to keep up.

Comment: Could you try with robolectric 3.2-SNAPSHOT?

Comment: tried with 3.2-SNAPSHOT but still the same error.

Answer (score 3):

Do you specifically require your tests to target **JELLYBEAN**?

Given you do specifically require your tests to target **JELLYBEAN**, you may want to put your v21+ assets in the `res/drawable-v21` folder **instead** of `res/drawable-anydpi-21`.

I too was recently getting the same error with tests after adding an `ImageView` to a layout that uses a `VectorDrawable` as its source.

```
<ImageView
    android:contentDescription="@string/content_image_description"
    android:src="@drawable/banner"
    android:layout_gravity="right"
    android:layout_width="@dimen/banner_width"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/banner_height"
    />
```

Using robolectric v3.1, I was able to get my tests to pass again with the following config annotation:

```
@Config(constants = BuildConfig.class, sdk = Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP, packageName = "com.package")
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

You can do one thing. Take the source of RoboElectric and replace all lines

```
ContextCompat.getDrawable(context, drawableId)
```

with

```
AppCompatDrawableManager.get().getDrawable(context, drawableId)
```

Compile roboelectric and use it. It will allow roboelectric to use vectors.